# Simple circuit to power a 4HP 180 V DC motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-motor

### Overview

I'm trying to make a cheap simple circuit to power and control the speed of the motor. It's going to drive a pulley and be used as simple woodsaw.

### Problems

- Running the motor without a resistor makes it lose control going too fast and smelling like burnt even when the dimmer is set to 120V
- Running with the resistor makes the resistor smoke

### Ideas

I may need to change the value of the resistor, or change it for something else to control the current, that's my question: What would fix this circuit ?

### Schematic

[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not Feasible

This linear method dissipates 50% of 3kW Motor power at maximum power transfer.

Any attempt to apply full voltage on a stationary motor also only sees the motor winding DCR which results in up to 10x surge current initially  ( or a fried resistor)

You need to buy a Motor Speed controller that matches your need to accelerate as a fraction of max acceleration which is 30kW initial power!!   Some physics skills needed here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Is there any other way or circuit to power this motor ? A controller for a 180V DC motor is too expensive for this son and dad project. This motor was removed from an old treadmill that the controller failed.

Comment: Not unless you have a budget for $150 or compromise on power, speed  with a 90V controller for half speed . Check Amazon etc.